# Menu items opening activities

Tags: java, android, menu

I have a menu on every activity besides my login screen of my app and I want the items to take me to each of their respective activities. All of the tutorials I see only display toast messages. I have one menu item working but am unsure of how I can add the rest.

this is from my activity.java file, it works, but I want to add the other buttons in line with this as well so that I can just copy and paste to my other activities.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_home) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, activityHome.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options:

- Use a single `Activity` with different `Fragment`s (and you can use the [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation))
- Use an abstract `BaseActivity` with the common code
- Create an util method to handle the common code in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

---

Option with an `BaseActivity`:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutId());
    }

    protected abstract @LayoutRes int getLayoutId();

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.search:
                //...
                return true;
            //...   
                 
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And then in each `Activity`:

```
public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == ... ){
            //Do something
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

Option with a util method:

```
public static boolean utilOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.search:
            //...
            return true;
        ///
    }
}
```

and in your

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
       if (item.getItemId() == ... ){
                //Do something
       }
       return Util.utilOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```